# Sql Script to find similar user records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have LawfirmUser table with `FirstName`, `LastName` and `userId` columns
below is some sample data of LawfirmUser

```
FirstName      LastName     userId
----------   -----------  ----------
Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
Demo            test3         6 
Demo            test4         7
```

Am trying to write a scriptto find all the records having same First and Last names but different userIds

the query should return below data

```
FirstName      LastName     userId
----------   -----------  ----------
Demo            test1         1
Demo            test1         2
Demo            test1         3
Demo            test2         4
Demo            test2         5
```

Am pretty beginner to sql stuff, Could someone please help me with the query?

Comment: you should look into Group by and Having,  group by first and last name having count(*) > 1

Comment: @Dan I had no idea of where to start on this script, So I posted here to get seek some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how it works

**CTE1,CTE2 etc are called Common Table Expressions in Sql Server which act as temporary tables
 which will not be stored in memory and gets cleared after execution of query.**

**1.** **CTE1** - Selects the distinct values from the table. For example, if the table have same `FirstName`,`LastName` and `UserId`, we should avoid that since you need to find the records of same `FirstName` and `LastName` for different `UserId`. 
**2.** **CTE2** - Select result from `CTE1` and we will count the same  `FirstName` and `LastName` for different `UserId`. The following image will explain the use of `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName)`

[image]

**3.** At last we will take the result where `CNT>1`.

Here is the working query.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM YOURTABLE
)
,CTE2 AS
(
   SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName,LastName) CNT
   FROM CTE1
)
SELECT FirstName,LastName,userId
FROM CTE2 
WHERE CNT>1
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b48a49/1)

[image]

Comment: I have added explanation with image from which you can easily understand. Feel free to ask for any help :) @RanPaul

Comment: The answer of NoDisplayName will not work if the table have same FirstName,LastName and UserId. My answer will work :) @RanPaul

Answer (score 3):

Use `Window Function`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName ORDER BY userid) rn
         FROM   YOURTABLE)
SELECT *
FROM   cte a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   cte b
               WHERE  a.FirstName = b.FirstName
                      AND a.LastName = b.LastName
                      AND rn > 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A self join would do it.

```
SELECT A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.userID
FROM lawfirmuser A
INNER JOIN lawFirmuser B 
  on A.FirstName = B.FirstName
 and A.LastName = B.LastName
 and A.UserID <> B.UserID
GROUP BY A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.userID
```

There may be more elegant ways however.  I don't believe this will suffer if the same first,last and userID exist in lawfirmuser.